# Clear Contents Of A For Loop Inside A For Loop At Each Pass

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, parse-platform

So, I'm taking Google Maps API return data & placing it into a parse.com database.

I am storing the address_component part of the JSON return in an array.

The overall JSON return may contain 1 location or several (depending on the search term used).  Here is my code:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                              var output = "";
                              var formattedAddress;
                              var lat;
                              var lng;
                              var types;
                              var comp;
                              var compCont;
                              var comp2 = [];
                              var compCont2 = [];
                              var i;
                              var j;
                              var k;
                              var l;

                              for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                                    formattedAddress = results[i].formatted_address;
                                    coordinates = results[i].geometry.location;
                                    lat = results[i].geometry.location.lat();
                                    lng = results[i].geometry.location.lng();

                                    types = results[i].types;

                                    var no = 1+i;

                                    output += "<li>";
                                    output += "<H1><i>"+ no +"</i></H1>"
                                    output += "<p><b>"+ formattedAddress +"</b></p>";
                                    output += "<p>"+ "lat: " + lat + ", lng: "+ lng +"</p>";
                                    output += "<p>"+ types +"</p>";
                                    for (j = 0; j < results[i].address_components.length; j++) {
                                          comp = results[i].address_components[j].types;
                                          compCont = results[i].address_components[j].long_name;
                                    output += "<p>"+ comp +": " + compCont +"</p>";
                                    }
                                    output += "</li>";


                                    for (k = 0; k < results[i].address_components.length; k++) {
                                          comp2.push(results[i].address_components[k].types);
                                          compCont2.push(results[i].address_components[k].long_name);
                                    }

                                    var Searches = Parse.Object.extend("Searches");
                                    var searches = new Searches();

                                    searches.set("Searched", name);
                                    searches.set("Returned_Address_Qty", no);
                                    searches.set("Address", formattedAddress);
                                    searches.set("Latitude", lat);
                                    searches.set("Longitude", lng);
                                    searches.set("Section", comp2);
                                    searches.set("Section_Content", compCont2);

                                    searches.save(null, {
                                          success: function(searches) {
                                          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
                                          // alert('New object created with objectId: ' + searches.id);
                                          },
                                          error: function(searches, error) {
                                          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                                          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                                          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
                                          }
                                    });

                                    $("#list-locations").html(output);

                              }
                        } else {
                              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
```

So, the issue comes when there are more than 1 result for the search query.  The first record sent to Parse contains the address_components in the array (comp2 & compCont2) as expected.

However, result 2 comp2 / compConts2 contains the address_components of result 1 & result 2, result 3 = 1, 2, 3 & so on.

So, I need a way that each time the outer for loop operates, it clears comp2 & compConts2.  I have tried:

```
comp2 = null;
```

&

```
comp2 = "";
```

Neither seem to work though & break the outer for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.push()` which expects both `comp2` and `compCont2` to be arrays, so have you tried clearing them by setting them back to their original value of being an empty array `comp2 = []; compCont2 = [];` inside your outer `for` loop? Or you could simply declare those array variables inside the loop, as what you want is a clean instance every time.